# How can I travel to a target, with a given speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm adding homing missiles to my game, but having some problems figure out how to travel to target, in the update. I've calculated the distance, and subracted speed over time from it.. but can I add it to position?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MissileScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Target;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(Target.transform.position, transform.position);
        distance -= .1 * Time.deltaTime;

        ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the distance. Also you should have a `Speed` value for your Game Object. Then you could do the following:

1. Calculate the direction vector
2. Normalize direction vector
3. Create a moving factor using `Speed` and `Time.deltaTime` values
4. Use `Transform.Translate` function to move the game object

Something like this:

```
public GameObject Target;
public float Speed;

void Update()
{
   Vector3 direction = Target.transform.position - this.transform.position;
   direction.Normalize();
   float factor = Time.deltaTime * Speed;
   this.transform.Translate(direction.x * factor, direction.y * factor, direction.z * factor, Space.World);
}
```

Comment: Change `Speed` value till you get the right velocity for the missil

Answer (score 0):

You should read about steering behaviours, and in particular seeking behaviours.
It's realy easing to implement and it is more realistic than simply using translation on a straight line.

Check this link: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-seek--gamedev-849